# How to change JNLP codebase value dynamically?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We are using jnlp file on server and provide the codebase value specific to jnlp folder. But it is not necessary that every time the server will be same and the jnlp may be deployed to different server on different machine. So, the codebase value has to be modified every time manually. Is there any way to set codebase value pragmatically no matter what will be the machine or server? JNLP should get codebase value automatically.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These days with tightened security requirements for JWS apps. it's really only possible to have a dynamic code base if the jars are also made and signed dynamically. This is because the code base needs to be written into the manifest of the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

The jnlp file does not have to be static, you can generate it with a servlet as a response to a request to the application server. The [JnlpDownloadServlet Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) describes this possibility in detail. The main point is

> You do not have to hardcode codebase URLs in the JNLP file.

An example implementation can be found in Java SE Development Kit 8u121 Demos and Samples [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) in sample/jnlp/servlet/src/classes/jnlp/sample/servlet/JnlpDownloadServlet.java .